# Excel Keeps Crashing when a file uses the "Get Data" feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

We just upgraded to the office 365 version of excel (retaining the desktop version also). all my files that used the Get Data option to connect to folders in the same directory or to our SQL server are no longer working - they crash each time. This is the message i get when i select the "debug" option: "an unhandled microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in EXCEL.EXE [8952]. it lists possible debuggers of new instance of Microsoft visual studio 2010 and 2012.

help!

Comment: Hey Elizabeth! I have not personally seen the error before, but I am curious if you are running the latest version of Dot Net. It may be worth checking that and upgrading if available. If so, it would be worth restarting after upgrade and before testing again.

Comment: You may want to check the patch notes for VBA changes made between these versions. I'm not sure where to find these, but I recall going through these 15 or so years ago at another job to rewrite VBA macros that would be affected by an Excel patch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Administrator privileges on you PC, try repairing your [MS Office installation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b). If you don't, ask your IT department to do it.